# Can I give a single MySQL schema two names?

Tags: mysql, sql, schema, naming, renaming

Is it possible to give a single schema two names, so that connecting to either:

```
jdbc:mysql://2.2.2.2:3306/name1
```

Or:

```
jdbc:mysql://2.2.2.2:3306/name2
```

Would  itconnect to the same schema?

Comment: Can you accomplish what you are attempting with Symbolic Links? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303049/how-do-i-alias-a-database-in-mysql

Comment: Don´t do that. MySQL handle the files on his own way. So when you write in one Schema the other can be cached and give you wrong results and when it also write it destroy the Table.

Comment: you can create a second Schema and create VIEWS for each table in the other Schema. So both handled from MySQL and you can access it.

Comment: Why do you want to access the Schema with to different names ?

Comment: ok i'll give symbolic links and/or view based method a try.  thanks!